# PO Box RegEx At the Start of a String

Tags: c#, regex

I've looked around this site for a good PO Box regex and didn't find any that I liked or worked consistently, so I tried my hand at making my own...  I feel pretty good about it, but I'm sure the kind folks here on SO can poke some holes in it :)  So... what problems do you see with this and what false-positives/false-negatives can you think up that would get through?

One caveat that I can see is that the PO Box pattern has to be at the start of the string, but what else is wrong with it?

```
public bool AddressContainsPOB(string Addr)
{
    string input = Addr.Trim().ToLower();
    bool Result = false;

    Regex regexObj1 = new Regex(@"^p(ost){0,1}(\.){0,1}(\s){0,2}o(ffice){0,1}(\.){0,1}((\s){1}|b{1}|[1-9]{1})");
    Regex regexObj2 = new Regex(@"^pob((\s){1}|[0-9]{1})");
    Regex regexObj3 = new Regex(@"^box((\s){1}|[0-9]{1})");

    Match match1 = regexObj1.Match(input);
    if (match1.Success)
    { Result = true; }
    Match match2 = regexObj2.Match(input);
    if (match2.Success)
    { Result = true; }
    Match match3 = regexObj3.Match(input);
    if (match3.Success)
    { Result = true; }
    return Result;
}
```

Comment: I am reading between the lines.  I have work with application that deal with addresses and the only way that I have found to reliable deal with Postal addresses to the CASS Certify them first and build your logic off of the results set that you get back. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_Accuracy_Support_System]

Comment: That's a very good point, Tim, I should definitely make a case for us to invest in some sort of CASS solution...  That would solve a lot of issues that we deal with frequently, well above and beyond handling PO Boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect from us? You don't even give us valid/invalid strings. Have you tested your regexes somehow?

What I see at the first glance, without knowing something about valid input is:

1. *One caveat that I can see is that the PO Box pattern has to be at the start of the string*

   Do you want to match it only at the start of the string or not? You need to know that and define it in your pattern. If you don't want to, then remove the start of the string anchor `^` and replace it with a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`.
2. `{1}` is superfluous, you can just remove it.
3. For `{0,1}` there is a shortform `?`, I like this better, because it is shorter.
4. `^box((\s){1}|[0-9]{1})` matches either "box" followed by a whitespace OR followed by a digit. Is this really what you want to match?
5. `(\.)` in the first regex: Why do you group a single dot?

Comment: thank you for adding some efficiency improvements, i will incorporate each of these (short of point 4 - that is the desired behavior)